# How to build XSL from XML for following example

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>11</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <catalog>
```

XSL as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        {
            "Details": {
                "your_requested_data" : "{\n<xsl:for-each select='catalog/cd' ><xsl:choose><xsl:when test='position() = last()'>\"data\" : [{\"price\":\"<xsl:value-of select='price' />\"}]</xsl:when></xsl:choose></xsl:for-each>}"
            }    
        }
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output I need is :

```
{
            "Details": {
                "your_requested_data" : "{\n \"data\" : [{\"price\":\"10\"},{\"price\":\"11\"}]}"
            }    
}
```

Basically I am trying to build stringify JSON from XML using XSLT.

Please suggest how to achieve it.

Comment: Are you limited to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" I am using

Comment: Please test your **processor** for the version it supports - see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: I don't understand your requested output. I would expect a "stringified JSON" to have all its double quotes escaped, not only some - e.g. `"{\"Details\" : { \"your_requested_data\" : { \"data\" : [ { \"price\" : \"10\"},{ \"price\" : \"11\"} ]}}}"`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k it's XSLT 3.0

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 or later or SaxonJS 2) you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="json" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:sequence
      select="map { 'details' : map { 'yourRequestedData' : serialize(map { 'data' : array { catalog/cd/price ! map { 'price' : number(.) } } }, map { 'method' : 'json' }) }}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Sample online fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22json%22%20indent%3D%22no%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20select%3D%22map%20%7B%20%27details%27%20%3A%20map%20%7B%20%27yourRequestedData%27%20%3A%20serialize%28map%20%7B%20%27data%27%20%3A%20array%20%7B%20catalog%2Fcd%2Fprice%20%21%20map%20%7B%20%27price%27%20%3A%20number%28.%29%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%2C%20map%20%7B%20%27method%27%20%3A%20%27json%27%20%7D%29%20%7D%7D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Ccatalog%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EEmpire%20Burlesque%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EBob%20Dylan%3C%2Fartist%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUSA%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EColumbia%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E10%3C%2Fprice%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1985%3C%2Fyear%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EEmpire%20Burlesque%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EBob%20Dylan%3C%2Fartist%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUSA%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EColumbia%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E11%3C%2Fprice%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1985%3C%2Fyear%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fcatalog%3E&input-type=XML).

Note that I have intentionally used the JSON and XPath number/xs:double data type for the price values instead of a string; if you really want a JSON string use e.g. `map { 'price' : string(.) }` instead of the used `map { 'price' : number(.) }`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you also help how to add more nodes ? like 

`{
            "Details": {
                "your_requested_data" : "{\n \"data\" : [{\"price\":\"10\"},{\"price\":\"11\"}], /"moreNode/": "abc"}"
            }    
}`

Comment: See a tutorial on XPath 3.1 maps https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3/xpath-31#maps